# ARM: Buffer Overrun debug help

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, embedded, buffer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello fellow ROSers.
I have compiled Fuerte from sources on an ACME FoxG20 board running embedian 6 wheezy (armv5tejl platform).
I am now attempting to compile the publisher/subscriber tutorial.

Everything appears to work, and it compiles fine.
Problem is: I always get this error

```
[ERROR] [1353939756.715474051]: Exception thrown when deserializing message of length [164] from [/add_two_ints_server]: Buffer Overrun
```

The same code runs flawlessly on my computer.
Whatever mixture of node topology I use, when any node (core, server, client... doesn't matter) is run on the ARM, I get this error.
I suspect it may have something to do with the network buffers, but I can't believe such a stupid example can overflow the buffer.

I already enlarged all TCP related buffers, so this shouldn't be the problem.
Where else should I look for a solution?

***Followup.***

doing a grep -lri "buffer overrun" in ros-underlay returns

```
roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/src/serialization.cpp
```

This here gives the function name

```
throwStreamOverrun()
```

Doing another grep on this yields:

```
roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/serialization.h
roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/src/serialization.cpp
```

Reading the serialization.h I did a grep on both ***ROSCPP_SERIALIZATION_DECL*** and ***StreamOverrunException*** whose result is

```
roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/roscpp_serialization_macros.h
roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/serialization.h
roscpp_core/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/serialized_message.h
```

Since this is leading me nowhere I decide to grep on the first part of the error message "Exception thrown when..." and this gives

```
ros-underlay/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/message_deserializer.cpp

try
  {
    SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParams params;
    params.buffer = serialized_message_.message_start;
    params.length = serialized_message_.num_bytes - (serialized_message_.message_start - serialized_message_.buf.get());
    params.connection_header = connection_header_;
    msg_ = helper_->deserialize(params);
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Exception thrown when deserializing message of length [%d] from [%s]: %s", (uint32_t)serialized_message_.num_bytes, (*connection_header_)["callerid"].c_str(), e.what());
  }
```

So somehow the try fails.
Now how do I debug this???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49136/arm:-buffer-overrun-debug-help/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2012-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would guess that your ARM machine is configured to run big-endian.  The ROS communication protocol uses little-endian on the wire and as far as I know, `roscpp`'s seralizer doesn't account for running on a big-endian host.

Adding big-endian support to `roscpp` has been [discussed](http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20090406.224609.a93dd141.fi.html).

But you can likely work around your problem by configuring your ARM machine to run as little-endian instead of big-endian.  There's usually a way to do that.

Btw, I would expect `rospy` to work properly across mixed-endian machines as it's using Python's `struct` module to implement serialization.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2012-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [enodiesop](https://answers.ros.org/users/3856/enodiesop/) on 2013-05-03**:
I am the same error with same architecture (AT91SAM9G25) and same debian version. I have build ros-groovy myself. With "dpkg-architecture" I know that my machine is little-endian. So, how I can resolve this error? Claudio, you have answer?

**Comment by [dave.peacock](https://answers.ros.org/users/12111/dave.peacock/) on 2014-02-25**:
Years later I run into the same problem, with ros-fuerte on an ARM host running squeeze. Host is little-endian, cross-compiled code says it is little endian. Saw some post on ros-users that mentioned sizeof int8 vs int32, maybe this is the problem. Can anyone shed light on what they found?